# How to find the directory of an app that is using your gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a gem that will access a configuration yaml file in the ruby app that the gem is required in. I've already checked out `Dir.pwd` but that only gives the directory that I am running the script from. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Here's sort of what I'm talking about.

The gem would have a constant which could be accessed by `Gem::CONSTANT`. The code that instantiates this constant would be

```
module Gem
  config_file = #code to retrieve the yaml file.
  CONSTANT = config_file[:constant]
end
```

Then other methods would perform operations on these constants. Any help would be appreciated let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: well that is the plan, but I would still have to retrieve the root directory of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `File.dirname($0)`.

`$0` is the absolute path/name of the currently running script.

Comment: I think that's the right track. What would be the way to find the root of the application then. Just go back a directory check if it's still in the git project and if it's not then go to the last directory and that's the root. Is there a better way?

Comment: There's no way to know where the root of an application is. The running file could be located anywhere in a folder hierarchy, depending on the application and how the developer laid things out. If the application is in `/usr/local/bin` on a host, it would be very wrong to insist the config file be located there.